# Find cells under a column in an HTML table with xpath?

Tags: html, xpath, html-table

I want to be able to extract all cells under a certain column with xpath.

There are/may be occasionally colspans.

Is there any way to do this, by which I suppose I'm asking, is there any inherent relationship between a table header and the cells below it? Or is there no inherent relationship and despite being fairly easy to do visually, its outside the ability of pure xpath?

**Scenario:**
We have an HTML table with a dozen columns and several rows. The columns have headers, and some of the column headers span more than one column.

One of those column headers (we don't know which one) has the textual content "Pick Me".

I want to be able to select all the cells *under* that cell in the table.

Comment: Please provide at a minimum, an .xml/.html sample.

Comment: I'm honestly not sure what benefit that would provide to this question, and every time I've provided one in response to a request (rather than because it actually added value to the problem), it's resulted either in the problem being ignored just as much as before, or people scrambling with completely incorrect answers roughly based on the example while ignoring the actual question. I'm pretty sure everyone who would be able to answer this question knows what a table looks like - what added value would a "sample" provide? I've heard this a bunch of times, so I'm actually interested here.

Comment: What kind of answer do you expect? I don't know Ruby, I don't know cells and columns. What I know is xml, html, xsl, xpath. How can I possibly help you?

Comment: There, thank you, I think with that last comment I actually got some idea of what the problem was. I've rephrased the question, hopefully in a way that is clearer. Though I'm guessing simply referring to it as an "HTML Table" would have accomplished the same thing?

Comment: You must also write what exactly you want to extract. Right now I don't understand what you want to extract. You say that you want to extract all cells under a column? Which exactly is this column?

Comment: Any of them. All of them. Although in my example, I did specifically say "This is the one I want - the one under col2", so assume that's what I'm looking for for now. Yes, it's only one cell, for now, but if I can find one then I should be able to find the others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no association in xpath between column headers in a table and the column they fall within.

The only way to find cells that fall beneath a specific column header is, using some other code, to count the columns (account for colspans) until the desired table header is found, and then count that many columns in each row to extract the cells.

Comment: I like that you answer with my comment, and you post it as your comment and then accept the answer. You really are amazing.

Comment: I waited to see if you were you going to post it as the answer, since I said it was correct. You didn't, so I did. If someone else comes along and wants to reference this question/answer, they shouldn't have to dig through the comments to find the answer. Should I have edited your answer instead? I'm honestly not sure what the proper protocol would have been for this situation. Your answer was still /wrong/, after all, even if you answered in the comments.

Comment: @FailedDev, SO is not here so that you can get high reputation, it's here to answer questions. Flagging actual good answer as “not and answer” (I assume it was you) is pointless.

Comment: I wiki'd the answer so that no rep can accrue.  I trust this satisfies everybody.

Comment: @svick You don't know the history of this post, and you also don't see my deleted answer. As well as the countless edits of the original question. I undeleted my answer - which of course now seems **WRONG** but if you had seen the question at the time I answered you would have seen that it was actually correct. Also please see the OP comment under my answer. Not rude at all right? I could not care less about rep.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it in XPath 1.  I assume that only one column has the desired header and the rowspan attribute does not occur.

```
tbody/tr/td[
      count(preceding-sibling::td[not(@colspan)])
      + sum(preceding-sibling::td/@colspan)
    = count(../../tr[1]/th[.='Pick Me']/preceding-sibling::th[not(@colspan)])
      + sum(../../tr[1]/th[.='Pick Me']/preceding-sibling::th/@colspan)]
```

The above expression yields all cells *starting* in the *leftmost* column of the Pick Me header.  By duplicating a lot of the logic, you can get the cells starting in *any* column spanned by Pick Me or the cells *sharing* a column with Pick Me, perhaps the broadest interpretation of your question:

```
tbody/tr/td[
      count(preceding-sibling::td[not(@colspan)])
      + sum(preceding-sibling::td/@colspan)
    < count(../../tr[1]/th[.='Pick Me']/preceding-sibling::th[not(@colspan)])
      + sum(../../tr[1]/th[.='Pick Me']/preceding-sibling::th/@colspan)
      + count(../../tr[1]/th[.='Pick Me'][not(@colspan)])
      + sum(../../tr[1]/th[.='Pick Me']/@colspan)
  and count(preceding-sibling::td[not(@colspan)])
      + sum(preceding-sibling::td/@colspan)
      + not(@colspan)
      + sum(@colspan)
    > count(../../tr[1]/th[.='Pick Me']/preceding-sibling::th[not(@colspan)])
      + sum(../../tr[1]/th[.='Pick Me']/preceding-sibling::th/@colspan)]
```

The strategy here is to compute the "position" of both the left and right side of each cell and the Pick Me header, where "position" means the number of columns to something's left.  The cell overlaps the header's column(s) if, and only if, the cell's left is left of the header's right and the cell's right is right of the header's left.  That is the meaning of the numeric comparisons.

Answer (score 0):

In case you need to grab specific column for example the first:

```
//tr/td[1]
```